# Should the review window provide more question detail?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

I have recently found myself reviewing a lot of posts on stack overflow and it seems to me as if it could be easier to review certain posts for different issues.

[image: image of late answer review]

For example:
When reviewing late answers by new users the only information I am given is the following as seen in the above image:

- New Answer
- Original Question
- How many other people answered
- Whether an answer was accepted

As I understand it, one of the things I should be looking for when reviewing new answers to old posts (Necros) is whether the new answer contributes something new or updated that the older answers didn't. That however is impossible for me to do from this window without going to look at what the other answers were.

There are many other examples of issues that I think can only really be determined by looking at the other answers that a question has received. Should Stack Overflow have some sort of functionality to allow a reviewer to see more detail (i.e. top answers to a question) when reviewing posts?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not very widely advertised, but the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script includes a feature that shows (other) answers below each review question.  Here's a screenshot of it in action (click to enlarge):

[image: Screenshot of SOUP review answer display]

Note how the extra answers are shown grayed-out, just like the question already shown by the standard review interface, to keep them from distracting you from the main focus of the review.  Typically, they also fall below the bottom of the page, so you'll need to scroll down to see them; when you want the extra context, though, that's still more convenient than opening a separate tab.

The way SOUP implements this feature is by fetching the full question page using a jQuery AJAX request, extracting the (other) answers and restyling them to match the review page.  This feels klugy, but seems to work very well in practice.  There are a few occasional quirks with review audits, such as answers failing to show up if the question has been deleted and you don't have enough rep to view it, but those are minor enough that you'll only notice them if you're paying attention (which is how audits are *supposed* to work).

In case you're curious, or want to extract this feature into a separate user script, here's the code from SOUP that implements it:

```
if ( ! /^\/review\b/.test( location.pathname ) ) return;
SOUP.hookAjax( /^\/review\/(next-task|task-reviewed)\b/, function () {
    $('.reviewable-post').not(':has(.answer)').each( function () {
        var post = $(this), question = post.find('.question');

        // initial check to see if there are any answers to load
        var label = post.find('.reviewable-post-stats td.label-key:contains("answers")');
        var count = label.first().next('td.label-value').text().trim();
        var shown = $('.reviewable-answer').length;  // XXX: don't needlessly reload sole answers in answer review
        if ( count - shown < 1 ) return;

        // find question URL
        var url = post.find('h1 a.question-hyperlink').attr('href');
        SOUP.log( 'soup loading ' + (count - shown) + ' missing answers from ' + url );

        var injectAnswers = function ( html ) {
            // kluge: disable script tags; $.parseHTML() would be better, but needs jQuery 1.8+
            var answers = $( html.replace( /(<\/?)(script)/ig, '$1disabled$2' ) ).find('.answer').filter( function () {
                return ! document.getElementById( this.id );
            } ), n = answers.length;
            SOUP.log( 'soup loaded ' + n + ' missing answers from ' + url );

            // mangle the answer wrappers to look like the review page before injecting them
            answers.find('.votecell a[class^="vote-"], .post-menu > *, .comments, .comments-link').remove();
            answers.find('.vote-count-post').after( function () {
                return '<div>vote' + ( this.textContent.trim() == 1 ? '' : 's' ) + '</div>';
            } );

            // inject answers into the review page
            var header = $('<div id="answers-header"><div class="subheader answers-subheader"><h2></h2></div></div>');
            header.find('h2').text( n + ( shown ? ' Other' : '') + ' Answer' + ( n == 1 ? '' : 's' ) );
            header.insertAfter( question );
            answers.insertAfter( header ).mathjax();
        };
        $.ajax( { method: 'GET', url: url, dataType: 'html', success: injectAnswers } );
    } );
} ).code();
```

It does use a few SOUP-specific utility methods, but those are pretty trivial: `SOUP.log()` is just a thin wrapper around `console.log()`, and is only used for debugging, while `SOUP.hookAjax()` is a wrapper around jQuery's `ajaxComplete()` that takes a regex and function, and re-runs the function after each jQuery AJAX request to a URL matching the regex.  Here, it's used to fetch the answers whenever a new review item is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The page provides enough information for the majority of situations.  For those unusual situations where it *isn't* enough information, you can always follow the link to the question itself.  By including more information from review you save one click for the unusual cases but you over-complicate and draw attention away from the useful information for the vast majority of reviews.

Comment: But an issue here is that you never know if the new answer is a dupe of others until you click to go to the question and this could happen with *any* answer in the queue. As the OP points out, "one of the things I should be looking for when reviewing new answers to old posts (Necros) is whether the new answer contributes something new or updated that the older answers didn't. "

Comment: @codeMagic You can get some idea by looking at the votes on the question and the number of other answers.  When there are a ton of votes and answers, as in the quoted screenshot, there's pretty high odds of it being worth checking out.

Comment: Sure, you can get "some idea", but if there is even one other answer then you really have no way of knowing. When I review those myself I find I'm looking through the post when there are **any** other answers. I'm not sure that a scrollable container with the other answers would be too distracting from the task...

Comment: I feel like it should be an option, maybe in another tab or something. I just feel there are so many times i'm reviewing posts and I feel like the info I need isn't there

Comment: @secretformula If it's in another tab then it's still one click away.  it's 1 click away *already*.  That doesn't really make it any more accessible.

Comment: but it keeps the cohesiveness of the review window. The review area has a work flow setup for taking action based on the reviewers interpretation or the posts. In this case all the info NEEDED to perform a good job of reviewing is not in the hands of the reviewer without leaving the review area which is poor UI

Comment: @secretformula I don't see it as a poor UI though.  It's just not difficult to go look at the actual question.